# How to map JSON response to Model in Angular 4

Tags: json, angular, angular4-httpclient

I have tried a lot but I am not able to get endpoint response mapped to my model. I am using HttpClient and Angular4. 
I got data back from service but it is not mapped correctly to my model class.

I have following JSON which service is Returning:

```
{
    "result": [
        {
            "id": "1",
            "type": "User",
            "contactinfo": {
                "zipcode": 1111,
                "name": "username"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I have created a model in typescript which I will like to map to json response:

```
export interface result {
            zipcode: number;
            name: string;
}
```

This is how i call JSON endpoint.

```
result : string[] = [];

constructor(private http: HttpClient) {    }

public getList(): result[] {
        this.http.get<result[]>('url...', { headers: this.headers }).subscribe(

            data => {
             // 1. Data is returned - Working
                console.log('data: ' + data); 
                this.result= data;

                // This is the problem. My data is not mapped to my model. If I do following a null is returned
                console.log('data mapped: ' + this.result[0].name);
            },
            (err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
    // log error
            }
        );

        return this.result;
    }
```

Comment: your interface is wrong. where are the missing properties `id,type,contact info`

Comment: I only need zipcode and name that why I have created a interface with only those fields. Should Interface contains all the fields which exists in JSON?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to import the interface in your component,

```
import { result } from '.result';
```

Your interface should look like,

```
interface RootObject {
  result: Result[];
}

interface Result {
  id: string;
  type: string;
  contactinfo: Contactinfo;
}

interface Contactinfo {
  zipcode: number;
  name: string;
}
```

and change the type of result as,

```
result : result;
```

and assign the result as,

```
this.result = data;
```

You can use http://www.jsontots.com/ to create the interface based on JSON

Comment: Same problem.  data.result.contactInfo is undefinded.

Comment: Now it is working. It did help me to create the model from jsontots.com. The code which fixed it was this: 

this.http.get<RootObject>(url,{ headers: myheaders}).subscribe(data => {console.log('data: ' + JSON.stringify(data.Result[0].contactInfo.name) );
}

Comment: Is there a reason to use interfaces instead of classes in this case?

Answer (score 0):

your "data" is an Object, with a property "result". result[] has a property called "contactInfo". in contactInfo you have the data you want, so

```
//you have no model, so NOT get<result[]>
this.http.get('url...', { headers: this.headers }).subscribe(
            data => {
                this.result= data.result[0].contactInfo;
            }
```

Comment: I tried with your input but data.result.contactInfo is giving error. data.result.contactInfo is undefinded.

Comment: @user2480218, sorry, I update my answer, result is an array. anyway check with console.log(data) the value of data.

Comment: I could not get it to work when I removed get<..Object>. This resulted still in undefined.

Comment: sorry again is **data.result[0].contactinfo** . I've just probe. But it's not magic. you only need make a console.log(data), console.log(data.result), console.log(data.result[0]) and console.log(data.result[0].contactinfo to see your data