# Angular: displaying a JSON API Call with several interfaces

Tags: angular, api

Im trying to display this information about weather cities, but im having trouble at the last moment, I think. The API is OpenWeatherMap and the call is based on the docs. I've checked this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48277372/how-to-map-json-response-to-model-in-angular-4), tried to follow its logic but my problem remains, data wont render, with the error "ERROR Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays."

This is my service:

```
export class WeatherService {

constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

forecast: RootObject;

getForecast() {
  const url = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?lat=35&lon=139&APPID=ef48ddb3926ce0283de7291a09fd253e';
  return <Observable<RootObject[]>> this.http.get(url)
  .pipe(
      retry(3),
      catchError(this.handleError));
}
```

This is the generated interface:

```
export interface RootObject {
  coord: Coord;
  sys: Sys;
  weather: Weather[];
  main: Main;
  wind: Wind;
  rain: Rain;
  clouds: Clouds;
  dt: number;
  id: number;
  name: string;
  cod: number;
}

interface Clouds {
  all: number;
}

interface Rain {
  '3h': number;
}

interface Wind {
  speed: number;
  deg: number;
}

interface Main {
  temp: number;
  humidity: number;
  pressure: number;
  temp_min: number;
  temp_max: number;
}

interface Weather {
  id: number;
  main: string;
  description: string;
  icon: string;
}

interface Sys {
  country: string;
  sunrise: number;
  sunset: number;
}

interface Coord {
  lon: number;
  lat: number;
}
```

The component:

```
export class MainComponent implements OnInit {

foreCast: RootObject[];

  constructor(private weatherService: WeatherService) {
    this.getForecast();
   }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

getForecast() {
  this.weatherService.getForecast()
  .subscribe(data => {
    this.foreCast = data;
    console.log(this.foreCast);
  });
}
```

And the HTML:

```
<ul *ngFor="let wind of foreCast">


<li>{{wind.speed}}</li>

</ul>
```

This the log I get:

[image]

All the imports are in place, and the console.log show's me the retrieved object. What am I missing in this mapping?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was quite simple: it was all about targeting a nested object and initializing the model

Service.TS:

```
getForecast(): Observable<RootObject[]> {
    const url = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?lat=35&lon=139&APPID=ef48ddb3926ce0283de7291a09fd253e';
    return this.http.get<RootObject[]>(url)
    .pipe(
      retry(3),
      catchError(this.handleError));

  }
```

Component:

```
forecasts: RootObject[] = []; //Initialize

  constructor(private weatherService: WeatherService) {
    this.getForecast();
  }

  getForecast() {
    this.weatherService.getForecast()
      .subscribe(data => {
        this.forecasts = data;
        console.log(this.forecasts);
      });
  }
```

And the main problem, rendering the data:

```
<div class="container" >
  <ul *ngFor="let list of forecasts.list">
      <li>{{list.dt}}</li>
      </ul>
</div>
```

I was aiming not deep enough because the fetched data is a nested object

Answer (score 0):

As the error log says, it seems like you are iterating over an object and not an array. 
What does the console.log say?

I am assuming that you are not getting an array, but a object.

Another thing is the usage of the getForecast method. The httpClient always returns a Observable, you can only determine the type you expect:

```
getForecast():Observable<RootObject[]> {
  const url = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?lat=35&lon=139&APPID=ef48ddb3926ce0283de7291a09fd253e';
  return this.http.get<RootObject[]>(url)
  .pipe(
      retry(3),
      catchError(this.handleError));
}
```

Comment: I've edited the answer with a pic. I know that I get an object, but i thought i was inserting that in object type array?

Comment: well, now i get this error: ReferenceError: map is not defined

Answer (score 0):

I now had a deeper look into you rest api. 
Assuming that you want to list always the speed of the wind you have to do the following:

```
getForecast():Observable<RootObject[]> {
  const url = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?lat=35&lon=139&APPID=ef48ddb3926ce0283de7291a09fd253e';
  return this.http.get<RootObject[]>(url)
  .pipe(
      map(res => res.list)
      retry(3),
      catchError(this.handleError));
}
```

in your template:

```
<ul *ngFor="let obj of foreCast">
  <li>{{obj.wind.speed}}</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: wait, im having trouble with the map, i guess i miss an import

Comment: I've prepared an example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-1qbdv6 

copy the snippets, it will not work in stackblitz directly cause your api is not provided over a secured connection

Comment: thank you for the support, im sorry for the late reply, i was out of the office, im gonna try your example

Comment: wonderful, it works now...I dont know wich answer to vote, feel free to edit or delete any, and thanks again :)

Comment: well @fabi_k, your solution works, I get the data rendered, but im not using the interfaces, wich was the main purpose of this post...but thanks anyway